# Can't get permission to write to Desktop from ACCESS VBA

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, windows-10

Have this bit of code that transfers a cross tab query results to an EXCEL spreadsheet that I want on the desktop:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"1ACTSKUbyYrbyMo", _
"C:\Users\John\Desktop", _
True
```

But when I run it I get Run-time error '3051'  which says some else has the folder open or I do not have permission to write to the folder.  I have crawled all over the web and tried every possible solution I found, but nothing works. I go to the folder and right clock properties and uncheck read only, it does some sort of scan, but then always returns to read only.  Using Windows 10 and ACCESS 365 which I am beginning to believe is a mistake. I bet I've found and tried a dozen variations of fixes for the problem, but nothing works. Any suggestions?

jpl458

Comment: Do you tried to export it to other folder like document folder or other drive. What happens then? Also try with slash after desktop like `C:\Users\John\Desktop\\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the *filename*, not the folder name:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"1ACTSKUbyYrbyMo", _
"C:\Users\John\Desktop\YourNewWorkbook.xlsx", _
True
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. It seems like the correct answer to me. If it isn't, then please say so, so we can research the problem further and provide a correct answer.

Comment: Worked just fine.  Thanks for the help